# Running commands after ampersand symbol & in a remote ssh session

Tags: shell-script, ssh, job-control, concurrency

I have a shell script that initiates a long, resource-intensive command on several different machines.

In order to execute the script on each machine in parallel, I have an ampersand symbol after each remote command in the for-loop.

`initialize-cluster.sh`:

```
while read host; 
do
    ssh -f "$host" \"/home/user/allocate.sh\" &
done < ~/cluster
```

However, as a consequence, I do not get the shell prompt back at the end of the for-loop.
This prevents me from executing other scripts after `initialize-cluster.sh` has finished running `allocate.sh` on all of the machines.

For example, I want to be able to run a command such as:

```
./initalize-cluster.sh && ./execute-something-else.sh
```

However, currently `initialize-cluster` never "finishes."

I'd like subsequent commands to execute only after all of the `allocate.sh` scripts finish on the remote machines.

Comment: There is a #!/bin/sh. My intention was to provide the meaty part of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing in this script should prevent execution of the next command or return to the shell prompt. What could be giving the impression that the prompt is gone is the output of the remote scripts, which would arrive after return to the shell. To avoid that you could redirect stdout/stderr to some log file.

Since the remote commands are run in the background the original script will finish **before** the `allocate` scripts have finished executing: the next command can't assume that initialization is complete. In order to start all initializations in parallel and wait for them all to finish you could do the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
while read host 
do
  ssh "$host" "/home/user/allocate.sh" &
done < ~/cluster
wait
```

And then it should be possible to:

```
./initialize-cluster.sh && ./execute-something-else.sh
```

The key here is the `wait` command, which waits for child processes to finish.

Comment: There seems to be an error... Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

Comment: which shell? works for me in bash

Comment: you're right, if I change shebang to `#!/bin/sh` (which is `dash` on my system) I get the same error.

Comment: simplified it to work in more shells. I was overthinking it.